# Update HTML5 canvas rectangle on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've got some code which draws a rectangle on a canvas, but I want that rectangle to change color when I hover the mouse over it.

The problem is after I've drawn the rectangle I'm not sure how I select it again to make the adjustment.

What I want to do:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.stroke();

$('c.[rectangle]').hover(function(this){
    this.fillStyle = 'red';
    this.fill();
});
```

Comment: A canvas is just pixels, there are no objects in it for you to select. You can neither set an event listener on, nor change the properties of, previously drawn shapes. Use SVG (or plain HTML for a rectangle), or a library, unless you want to write a whole lot of low level code.

Comment: If you want the stuff you draw to have event listeners etc., use SVG instead.

Comment: As you can probably tell I'm new to HTML canvas, but as I understand HTML5 games are often built using them, so how would that work without event listeners?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't do this out-of-the-box with canvas. Canvas is just a bitmap, so the hover logic has to be implemented manually.

## Here is how:

- Store all the rectangles you want as simple object
- For each mouse move on the canvas element:

  - Get mouse position
  - Iterate through the list of objects
  - use isPointInPath() to detect a "hover"
  - Redraw both states

**Example**

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    rects = [
        {x: 10, y: 10, w: 200, h: 50},
        {x: 50, y: 70, w: 150, h: 30}    // etc.
    ], i = 0, r;

// render initial rects.
while(r = rects[i++]) ctx.rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue"; ctx.fill();

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

  // important: correct mouse position:
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      y = e.clientY - rect.top,
      i = 0, r;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // for demo
   
  while(r = rects[i++]) {
    // add a single rect to path:
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);    
    
    // check if we hover it, fill red, if not fill it blue
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.isPointInPath(x, y) ? "red" : "blue";
    ctx.fill();
  }

};
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

Comment: It won't work as well if a rectangle is over another rectangle. Check my answer to get idea, so you can update it.

Comment: It's not just that. You must do a 'DESC' to 'ASC' loop -- because of the rectangles index. In this 'DESC' loop you construct a render queue of the rectangles or just check if the mouse hits one and break, while in the normal loop you just render them.

Comment: I see, but it's better to keep no basic bugs in the code.

Comment: @Matheus there are no bugs, just no support for z-order

Comment: But yeah, it's a missing. See yourself two rectangles taking hover in same time. I have made snippet in my answer to show a example of solution.

Comment: How if i want a hover for object that are not canvas

Answer (score 17):

This is a stable code in base of @K3N answer. The basic problem of his code is because when one box is over the another the two may get mouse hover at same time. My answer perfectly solves that adding a 'DESC' to 'ASC' loop.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var map = [
    {x: 20, y: 20, w: 60, h: 60},
    {x: 30, y: 50, w: 76, h: 60}
];

var hover = false, id;
var _i, _b;
function renderMap() {
    for(_i = 0; _b = map[_i]; _i ++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = (hover && id === _i) ? "red" : "blue";
        ctx.fillRect(_b.x, _b.y, _b.w, _b.h);
    }
}
// Render everything
renderMap();
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // Get the current mouse position
    var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - r.left, y = e.clientY - r.top;
    hover = false;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for(var i = map.length - 1, b; b = map[i]; i--) {
        if(x >= b.x && x <= b.x + b.w &&
           y >= b.y && y <= b.y + b.h) {
            // The mouse honestly hits the rect
            hover = true;
            id = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Draw the rectangles by Z (ASC)
    renderMap();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

Below code adds shadow to canvas circle on hovering it.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</body>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    circle = [{
        x: 60,
        y: 50,
        r: 40,
      },
      {
        x: 100,
        y: 150,
        r: 50,
      } // etc.
    ];

  // render initial rects.
  for (var i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle[i].x, circle[i].y, circle[i].r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
  }

  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX,
      y = e.pageY,
      i = 0,
      r;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (let i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
      if ((x > circle[i].x - circle[i].r) && (y > circle[i].y - circle[i].r) && (x < circle[i].x + circle[i].r) && (y < circle[i].y + circle[i].r)) {


        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle[i].x, circle[i].y, circle[i].r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
        ctx.shadowColor = 'grey';
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.shadowColor = 'white';
        ctx.shadowBlur = 0;

      } else {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle[i].x, circle[i].y, circle[i].r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.shadowColor = 'white';
        ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
      }

    }

  };
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a slightly more in-depth answer that would work better for you, especially if you are interested in game design with the canvas element.

The main reason this would work better for you is because it focuses more on an OOP (object orientated programming) approach. This allows for objects to be defined, tracked and altered at a later time via some event or circumstance. It also allows for easy scaling of your code and in my opinion is just more readable and organized.

Essentially what you have here is two shapes colliding. The cursor and the individual point / object it hovers over. With basic squares, rectangles or circles this isn't too bad. But, if you are comparing two more unique shapes, you'll need to read up more on [Separating Axis Theorem (SAT)](https://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/sat/) and other collision techniques. At that point optimizing and performance will become a concern, but for now I think this is the optimal approach.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
const height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const cx = width / 2;
const cy = height / 2;
const twoPie = Math.PI * 2;
const points = []; // This will be the array we store our hover points in later

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r || 0;
  }
}

class HoverPoint extends Point {
  constructor(x, y, r, color, hoverColor) {
    super(x, y, r);
    this.color = color;
    this.hoverColor = hoverColor;
    this.hovered = false;
    this.path = new Path2D();
  }

  draw() {
    this.hovered ? ctx.fillStyle = this.hoverColor : ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    this.path.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, twoPie);
    ctx.fill(this.path);
  }
}

class Cursor extends Point {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    super(x, y, r);
  }

  collisionCheck(points) {
  // This is the method that will be called during the animate function that 
  // will check the cursors position against each of our objects in the points array.
    document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    points.forEach(point => {
      point.hovered = false;
      if (ctx.isPointInPath(point.path, this.x, this.y)) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        point.hovered = true;
      }
    });
  }
}

function createPoints() {
  // Create your points and add them to the points array.
  points.push(new HoverPoint(cx, cy, 100, 'red', 'coral'));
  points.push(new HoverPoint(cx + 250, cy - 100, 50, 'teal', 'skyBlue'));
  // ....
}

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  points.forEach(point => point.draw());
}

function animate(e) {
  const cursor = new Cursor(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  update();
  cursor.collisionCheck(points);
}

createPoints();
update();
canvas.onmousemove = animate;
```

There is one more thing that I would like to suggest. I haven't done tests on this yet but I suspect that using some simple trigonometry to detect if our circular objects collide would preform better over the ctx.IsPointInPath() method.

However if you are using more complex paths and shapes, then the ctx.IsPointInPath() method would most likely be the way to go. if not some other more extensive form of collision detection as I mentioned earlier.

The resulting change would look like this...

```
class Cursor extends Point {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    super(x, y, r);
  }

  collisionCheck(points) {
    document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    points.forEach(point => {
      let dx = point.x - this.x;
      let dy = point.y - this.y;
      let distance = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
      let dr = point.r + this.r;

      point.hovered = false;
      // If the distance between the two objects is less then their combined radius
      // then they must be touching.
      if (distance < dr) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        point.hovered = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

here is a link containing examples an other links related to [collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)

I hope you can see how easily something like this can be modified and used in games and whatever else. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to track the mouse on the canvas using JavaScript and see when it is over your rectangle and change the color then. See code below from my [blog post](http://dwightreid.com/blog/2015/03/27/html5-canvas-change-element-color-when-mouse-over/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
var myRect={x:150, y:75, w:50, h:50, color:"red"};
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = myRect.color;
ctx.fillRect(myRect.x, myRect.y, myRect.w, myRect.h);

c.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
if ((e.clientX>=myRect.x)&(e.clientX<=myRect.x+myRect.w)&(e.clientY>=myRect.y)&(e.clientY<=myRect.y+myRect.h)){
myRect.color = "green";}
else{
myRect.color = "red";}
updateCanvas();
}, false);


function updateCanvas(){
ctx.fillStyle = myRect.color;
ctx.fillRect(myRect.x, myRect.y, myRect.w, myRect.h);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My answer would be fairly much the same as yours: https://jsfiddle.net/e3tqwL0x/1/. You might explain a bit about how your solution works ;-)

Comment: In a nut shell, the event listener gets active when the mouse moves on the canvas, the position of the mouse (e.clientX and e.clientY) is then checked to see if it is in the bounds of the rectangle,   if it is  then the color of myRect is changed, the updateCanvas function then redraws the rectangle with the new color (from myRect).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I am surprised no one has mentioned JCanvas. It adds to the simplicity of animating canvas on events. More documentation here https://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/docs/mouseEvents/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- css and other -->
</head>
<body onload="draw();">
<canvas id = "canvas" width="500" height="500" style= border:1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>
<script>
function draw() {
    $('canvas').drawRect({
        layer: true,
        fillStyle:'#333',
        x:100, y: 200,
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        mouseover: function(layer) {
                $(this).animateLayer(layer, {
                    fillStyle: 'green'
                 }, 1000, 'swing');
                }
    }); 
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcanvas/21.0.1/jcanvas.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider this following code:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.stroke();

c.addEventListener("mouseover", doMouseOver, false);//added event to canvas

function doMouseOver(e){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/my0xefew/1/)

Comment: But I don't want to fill the whole canvas, I want to fill the different rectangles on it

Answer (score -2):

You could use canvas.addEventListener

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas0');
canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { /*your code*/ }, false);
```

It worked on google chrome

Answer (score -3):

```js
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    $(c).hover(function(e){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"/>
```

Comment: @Manwal, did you added jQuery reference?

Comment: @Manwal, please check the snippet provided in question

Comment: What? No blur-handler to remove the red when leaving.