# How to change the color of objects on hover in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm fairly new to Javascript/Canvas and I wanted to create an animation that creates circles whenever I click within the canvas, then it changes colors when I hover over them and reverts back to the original color when the mouse is not hovering over them. I was able to create the animation of drawing circles on click, but can't get the hover color to work. I'm trying to get this done completely with Javascript, using HTML only for creating the canvas. Any advice is appreciate!

```js
    let dots = [];

    /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
    let canvas = ( /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */ document.getElementById("canvas"));
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //some state
    let mouseX = -10;
    let mouseY = -10;

    //remember mouse click position
    canvas.onclick = function (event) {
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;

        let box = (event.target).getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseX -= box.left;
        mouseY -= box.top;
    };

    canvas.onmouseleave = function () {
        mouseX = -10;
        mouseY = -10;
    };

    var drawCirc = function (hover) {
        //clear the canvas
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        //determine mouse location when outside
        //if inwide canvas, make a dot
        if ((mouseX > 0) && (mouseY > 0)) {
            dots.push({
                "x": mouseX,
                "y": mouseY
            });
        }

        //draw circles/dots
        dots.forEach(function (d) {
            context.fillStyle = "#808080";
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(d.x - 3, d.y - 3, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.fill();
        });
        window.requestAnimationFrame(drawCirc);
    }
    drawCirc();
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Better check [mcve], and improve your question a bit :)

Comment: DOM objects have interfaces that can do things like trigger listeners when the cursor hovers over them. Shapes within a canvas do not have those interfaces, so if you want that behaviour, you'll have to program it, e.g. [*Mouse hover canvas/shape*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725832/mouse-hover-canvas-shape) (ignore the jQuery tag).

Answer (score -1):

**Javascript:**

```
object.addEventListener("mouseover", myScript);
```

example:

```
var e = document.getElementById('elementID')

e.onmouseover = function(){e.style.backgroundColor = "blue"}
```

Comment: And *myScript* should be…?

Comment: added one example

Comment: The OP is talking about hovering over a path drawn in a canvas element, not a DOM element. Canvas paths aren't DOM objects, they don't have DOM attributes or interfaces, you can't attach listeners to them.

Answer (score -1):

you can use mousehover method

for jquery here's the sample

```
$("p").mouseover(function(){
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
 });
```

for javascript

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
   document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

   function mouseOver() {
   document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
   }

   function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "black";
    }
</script>
```