# How do I have my cursor become a pointer (pointer-finger) when I hover over my box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function draw() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('Background');
if (canvas.getContext) {
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

ctx.lineWidth = 0.4
ctx.strokeRect(15, 135, 240, 40)
```

so I want the mouse to turn into a pointer finger when hovering over this simple line rectangle. How do I do that?

Comment: Simply use css with the `:hover` pseudo-class and `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: @ValentinDuboscq  He's talking about putting a hand on a rectangle that's been drawn using canvas.  CSS won't help here.  Personally I would use SVG's, and then you can use CSS again.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300280/update-html5-canvas-rectangle-on-hover) will help then

Comment: @ValentinDuboscq  Yes, that's the problem the op is having,..  I'm flagging that link as a dupe..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update HTML5 canvas rectangle on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300280/update-html5-canvas-rectangle-on-hover)

Answer (score -1):

The hover() method specifies two functions to run when the mouse pointer hovers over the selected elements.

This method triggers both the mouseenter and mouseleave events.
Syntax:
$(selector).hover(inFunction,outFunction)

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_hover

Comment: This has the same issue as the CSS, the target is the canvas element, not the rectangle drawn on the canvas..