# Hover effect on path inside canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a path inside the canvas I want to add a hover effect on each shape. When the user hovers on the shape I want to transparent the background color of the shape. As of now, I have attached the hover function to the canvas but I want to attach it to the shape.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');  
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
// ctx.fillStyle = "green";
// ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150)

// ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
// ctx.fillText("hello workd", 0, 10)


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(350,100)
ctx.lineTo(500,95)
ctx.lineTo(500,130)
ctx.lineTo(350,135)
ctx.lineTo(100,130)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill()
ctx.lineWidth = 10
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
ctx.stroke()



ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,200);
ctx.lineTo(350,200)
ctx.lineTo(500,195)
ctx.lineTo(500,230)
ctx.lineTo(350,235)
ctx.lineTo(100,230)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill()
ctx.lineWidth = 10
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
ctx.stroke();

canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
    console.log('x', e.clientX)
    console.log('y', e.clientY)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
     body{
         background: red;
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         margin: 0;     
     }
     #canvas {
         background: white
     }
    </style>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<script src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at: [change colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300280/update-html5-canvas-rectangle-on-hover)

Answer (score 4):

### Point over paths 2D

You can use [isPointInPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) and [isPointInStroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInStroke) to check if a point is over the current path. Or to make it easier you can use the [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) object to hold the paths and pass that to the functions saving the need to create the path each time the mouse moves.

### Example

The example below uses [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) to create the two paths. The `mousemove` event then checks if the mouse is over a path using [isPointInPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath). If there is a change in which path (1, 2, or none) the canvas is cleared and the paths redrawn reflecting the new state.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), mouse = {x:0, y:0, overPath: null}; 
const styles = {
     default: {fillStyle: "#0C0", strokeStyle: "#F00", lineWidth: 4},
     over: {fillStyle: "#C008", strokeStyle: "#F0F8", lineWidth: 10},
};
const paths = [
    [100, 50, 350, 50, 500, 45, 500, 80, 350, 85, 100, 80],
    [100, 150, 350, 150, 500, 145, 500, 180, 350, 185, 100, 180],
].map(createPath);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
   mouse.x = e.offsetX;
   mouse.y = e.offsetY;
   checkMouseOver(paths);
   canvas.style.cursor = mouse.overPath ? "pointer" : "default"; 
});
function checkMouseOver(paths) {
    var over;
    for(const p of paths) { ctx.isPointInPath(p, mouse.x, mouse.y) && (over = p) }
    if (over !== mouse.overPath) {
        mouse.overPath = over;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 200);
        for (const p of paths) {
            if (p === over) { drawPath(p, styles.over) }
            else { drawPath(p) }
        }
    }
}
function createPath(path) {
    var i = 0, p = new Path2D;
    while (i < path.length) { p.lineTo(path[i++], path[i++]) }
    p.closePath();
    return p;       
}
function drawPath(path, style = styles.default) {
    Object.assign(ctx, style).fill(path);
    ctx.stroke(path);    
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```